# Improve Table Value Function Performance

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, query-performance

Could you please help me to improve the table valued function :

```
    Create Function [dbo].[xxx](@InvoiceId numeric(18 ,0) ,@InvoiceType int ,@ReceiptAccOwner int)
    Returns Table
    As
    Return(


    Select * From(

            Select N'InvoiceReceiptNo' + Cast(ROW_NUMBER() over(order by ir.ReceiptRecID) as nvarchar(10)) As row

                ,ir.StockHoldingInvoiceID As InvoiceId

                ,ir.ReceiptNo As ReceiptValue
                ,ir.ReceiptAccOwner
            from InvoiceReceipt As ir       
            Where  ir.ReceiptAccOwner = @ReceiptAccOwner
            And (
                   (ir.StockHoldingInvoiceID = @InvoiceId And @InvoiceType in(1 ,6 ,8) )
                 or(ir.THCInvoiceID = @InvoiceId And @InvoiceType = 2)
                 or(ir.EvaluatInvoiceID = @InvoiceId And @InvoiceType = 3)
                 or(ir.StripInvoiceID = @InvoiceId And @InvoiceType = 4)
                 or(ir.EvaluationExportInvoiceID = @InvoiceId And @InvoiceType = 5)
                 or(ir.ServiceInvoiceID = @InvoiceId And @InvoiceType = 7)
                 or(ir.MovementInvoiceId = @InvoiceId And @InvoiceType = 10)
                 or(ir.InterchangeReplicaInvoice = @InvoiceId And @InvoiceType = 11)
                 or(ir.MovementInvoiceId = @InvoiceId And @InvoiceType = 12)
                 or(ir.BLConsigneeChangeRequestInvoiceID = @InvoiceId And @InvoiceType = 15)
                 )

            UNION All

            Select N'InvoiceReceiptPrice' + Cast(ROW_NUMBER() over(order by ir.ReceiptRecID) as nvarchar(10)) As row

                ,ir.StockHoldingInvoiceID

                ,Cast(IsNull(ir.ReceiptPrice ,0) as nvarchar(20)) As ReceiptValue
                ,ir.ReceiptAccOwner
            from InvoiceReceipt As ir
            Where  ir.ReceiptAccOwner = @ReceiptAccOwner
            And (
                   (ir.StockHoldingInvoiceID = @InvoiceId And @InvoiceType in(1 ,6 ,8) )
                 or(ir.THCInvoiceID = @InvoiceId And @InvoiceType = 2)
                 or(ir.EvaluatInvoiceID = @InvoiceId And @InvoiceType = 3)
                 or(ir.StripInvoiceID = @InvoiceId And @InvoiceType = 4)
                 or(ir.EvaluationExportInvoiceID = @InvoiceId And @InvoiceType = 5)
                 or(ir.ServiceInvoiceID = @InvoiceId And @InvoiceType = 7)
                 or(ir.MovementInvoiceId = @InvoiceId And @InvoiceType = 10)
                 or(ir.InterchangeReplicaInvoice = @InvoiceId And @InvoiceType = 11)
                 or(ir.MovementInvoiceId = @InvoiceId And @InvoiceType = 12)
                 or(ir.BLConsigneeChangeRequestInvoiceID = @InvoiceId And @InvoiceType = 15)
                 )

    ) As tb
    pivot(
             Max(ReceiptValue) --,Sum(ReceiptPrice)
             For row in ([InvoiceReceiptNo1] ,[InvoiceReceiptNo2] ,[InvoiceReceiptNo3] ,[InvoiceReceiptNo4] ,[InvoiceReceiptNo5] ,[InvoiceReceiptNo6] 
                        ,[InvoiceReceiptPrice1] ,[InvoiceReceiptPrice2] ,[InvoiceReceiptPrice3] ,[InvoiceReceiptPrice4] ,[InvoiceReceiptPrice5] ,[InvoiceReceiptPrice6])
         )   piv


    )
```

i use this function in stored procedure with Outer apply in select statement ,
this function should be return only one record for per invoice.

XML Execution plan : 
Select *  from [dbo].[fn_GetInvoiceReceiptInfo](149735 , 1 ,1) 
https://anotepad.com/notes/wh34ey

Comment: Can you put the execution plan on pastetheplan.com and give us a link? It would help us see what's happening.

Comment: @RichBenner pastetheplan.com not opening for me.

Comment: Try this link https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/

Comment: @RichBenner Unfortunately not opening

Comment: Ok, i guess it's a firewall thing your end, works fine for me. Get the XML for the execution plan and add it as an edit to your question if you can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so looking at the execution plan you've provided you're doing `Key Lookups` which means that you can probably tune an index to decrease the execution time here.

At the moment, you're using the index `Relationship_82_FK` on the table `InvoiceReceipt` to return the two values `ReceiptRecID` and `StockHoldingInvoiceID`. Now, because this index doesn't contain all of the information that you need SQL is having to go back and look up against your clustered index to return the additional information. Try altering the index `Relationship_82_FK` to have `ReceiptAccHolder` and `ReceiptPrice` as included fields.

Answer (score 2):

The answer depends on what indexes you have. Unless you specifically detail what indexes you have and what get used, it's difficult to come up with a better solution.

For example, you have an aggregate window function, it can be made faster by changing the clustering index or adding a covering index for your specific query. However that would only make sense if this really is the bottleneck.

What does the execution plan say?

Another thing you might want to try is rewrite all the queries without `OR` in the `WHERE` clause and use `UNION ALL` for all queries. This would allow the database to parallelize your query.

Again, these are things you can try but whether they work or not depends on indexes and query plan bottleneck.